# Specflow - How to pass on the data which has brackets to the step definition without any data loss

Tags: bdd, specflow

I have a specflow test which looks like this

```
When I create a team with <TeamName> <MemberName> <MemberMobileNumber> successfully
Examples:
|TeamName|MemberName|MemberMobileNumber|
|Apple(RD) |James(Smith)|(09)1234567|
```

If you observe, we have brackets in the test data details and when I read the data, the data is distorted. Is there a way to write the step definition in such a way that the data is not distorted. 
The step definition looks like this

```
[When(@"I create a team with (.*) (.*) (.*) successfully")]
public void WhenICreateATeamWithTeam......{

}
```

Thanks a lot for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any data loses in your example:
[image]

I also tried with Table and it works well.

I got data loses when I tried to make steps like this:

```
[When(@"I create a team with \(.*) \(.*) \(.*)")]
```

My version of SpecFlow is 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

For given specification in .feature file as you showed in question:

```
Scenario Outline: workWork
   When I create a team with <TeamName> <MemberName> <MemberMobileNumber> successfully
   Examples:
   |TeamName    |MemberName     |MemberMobileNumber |
   |Apple(RD)   |James(Smith)   |(09)1234567        |
```

And for step definition like:

```
[When(@"I create a team with (.*) (.*) (.*) successfully")]
public void WhenICreateATeamWithAppleRDJamesSmithSuccessfully(string p0, string p1, string p2)
{

}
```

Then data inside p0, p1 and p2 parameters in step is as expected: p0 = "Apple(RD)", p1 = "James(Smith)", p3 = "(09)1234567".

There is 2nd way to do this, using "" for textual data in .feature file, and then follow that with ""(.*)"" in regular expression (in method generated in step.cs file) for every input parameter.

```
Scenario Outline: workWork
    When I create a team with <TeamName> <MemberName> <MemberMobileNumber> successfully
    Examples:
    |TeamName       |MemberName     |MemberMobileNumber |
    |"Apple(RD)"    |"James(Smith)" |"(09)1234567"      |

[When(@"I create a team with ""(.*)"" ""(.*)"" ""(.*)"" successfully")]
public void WhenICreateATeamWithAppleRDJamesSmithSuccessfully(string p0, string p1, string p2)
{

}
```